# Phonegap / Cordova - Windows Authentication

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

We have a mobile web application that is embedded in phongegap. Recent requirements want us to allow users to browse to our traditional IIS website through this mobile web app. The traditional web app is so deeply rooted in Windows Authentication that we must have users authenticate using it. Mobile browsers will prompt for this type of authentication but this does not seem to be the case for webview.

After a lot of research I do not seem to find any plugins or alternative methods to accomplish this. It seems like our only solution is to develop a custom phonegap plugin that handles this scenario.

Before we invest the time and resources into doing this I wanted to see if there were any alternative methods that I might be missing for allowing a user to authenticate via Windows Authentication through phonegap when browsing to our traditional web app.

Comment: can you try to reach out to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3912411/ellen) individual. She seems to be from microsoft as per her profile working on Hybrid apps.

Comment: Did you have any success with this?